# Apache Cassandra data storage reconfiguration

Tags: cassandra

I have my Cassandra data stored in /opt which has around 50G but now I see the data is filled and Cassandra shuts down because of the memory error. I see another folder which has more space. My question is,

1. If I copy the entire folder from /opt to /xyz/ and configure the cassandra.yaml to the /xyz/, will there be a data loss?
2. If I do nodetool remove the server where I have space issues, will my data be safe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes,  it will work. Simply stop Casssandra, move the data and reconfigure the data path in cassandra.yaml.
2. Doing `nodetool decommission` will make the node leave the cluster but it won't physically remove data from that node.

Comment: Just as a note, the only operation that actually removes data from a node is `nodetool cleanup`.

Comment: `nodetool cleanup` only cleanup those data which doesn't hold by the node. For example, if you add another node to your cluster, data will be redistributed. Every node will share data with the new node, those shared data need to be cleaned from the old node using `nodetool cleanup`. @CarlosRolo